# Updating failed Post in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am working on WordPress blog and just started to post a new post its giving error me "**Updating failed**". I am not able to edit the sample post and also not able to post a new article.

**WordPress Version**: 5.0.2

Any Idea to resolve this issue?

Thanks

[image]

**Browser Inspector View**

[image]

Comment: Hello, Update page also caused this error.
For that you have to install fresh and latest version of WordPress.

Comment: Are you using Gutenberg editor ?

Comment: OK! @AshishOdich right now using WordPress 5.0.2, let me install latest version of WordPress, what is the latest version of WordPress right away.

Comment: @developerme right now only installed two plugins i.e. 1) Akismet Anti-Spam 2) Hello Dolly

Comment: @AnjanKant, It worked for you?
Currently 5.0.2 is the latest version of WordPress and These 2 plugins are not causing any problem and by default it is deactivates.

Comment: @AshishOdich we are on the same issue?

Comment: For this type of issues i also created Ticket on Trac https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/45721

Comment: also you can check for what type of error causes this issue by doing WP_DEBUG true in your project root folder, wp-config.php

Comment: Could you please share the screenshot of chrome inspector

Comment: @developerme console snapshot?

Comment: Yes console snapshot

Comment: @developerme check now?

Comment: Please check this doc https://wordpress.org/support/topic/publishing-fail-after-update-to-wordpress-5-0/page/3/

Comment: OK! trying to edit php.ini file and restart server as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get rid of this issue, you have to change the permalink structure from the admin side.

Please read this article [Solution link](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/2565#issuecomment-325795437)

Comment: Me just installed classic editor and problem flew away. thanks for saving my time. your link helped me.

Answer (score 2):

This problem is caused by the Gutenberg editor.
If you're website is hosted by any hosting provider, use the classic editor.

If you're hosting your website on a VPS, and you're running on Apache, try adding

```
<Directory /path/to/your/website>
AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

To your virtual host.

Answer (score 1):

I saw the same problem occur when I would select certain Permalink settings (specifically ones that caused the site's .htaccess to contain anything other than a blank file).

The issue ended up being: I did not have mod-rewrite enabled on my server.

The fix: I uncommented the below (in httpd.conf) and the problem went away (and it stayed fixed no matter what Permalink settings I select in WordPress) (be sure to restart Apache after httpd.conf edits)

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

Answer (score 1):

WordPress permalinks error for "pretty permalinks" on a Google Cloud instance gives  404 error on all the pages even if created using the default permalink, reverting it back to "pretty permalinks".

I like "pretty permalinks" and found out the best solution for the above situation is to 
**Enable mod_rewrite in Apache:**
Then, goto
 Compute Engine>VM Instances > SSH

Type $: a2enmod rewrite
Type $: sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
then **Change: AllowOverride ALL from AllowOverride NONE**

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride ALL 
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Restart Apache Server: 
sudo service apache2 restart

It should now update, create posts/pages in "pretty permalinks" with default Gutenberg editor without giving 404 error.

Solves the Rest API error
https://www.praj.info

Answer (score 1):

My site was behind Cloudflare and this seemed to be the reason for this issue.

In order to fix it I just installed **cloudflare plugin** for wordpress.

Comment: Thanks. mine fixed using this method.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when you are working on the Gutenberg editor. You can use the classic editor to overcome this problem.
Go to the **plugins>add new**
Search for a classic editor plugin and install it.
If this doesn't work deactivate all plugins.
After, you disabled all plugins start enabling plugins one by one to see which one will break WordPress again.
Or you can see this article:- [fix WordPress updating failed while creating or publishing a post.](https://wpbloggerbasic.com/blogs/fix-wordpress-updating-failed/)

Answer (score 0):

Check the url in the wordpress setting, you probaly set website url as "http". It'll be fixed.